# Inno Setup string concatenation in #define directive

Tags: inno-setup

Did the Inno Setup website fail to document the `#define` directives or did I miss that somewhere? Is it permissible to define using defined strings and concatenate them?

```
#define MyApp ABC
#define MyAppVersion 1.2.1
#define MyFolder ?  ; what is the right syntax here to concatenate 
                    ; the two previously defined strings?
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is the section of help concerning defines:

http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=define

Regarding your example:

```
#define MyApp "ABC"
#define MyAppVersion "1.2.1"
#define MyFolder MyApp + MyAppVersion

#define MyFolder1 MyApp + "Some other string"
```

Comment: As of today (Dec 2017) that link does not seem to explicitly use the "+" operator and it does not define the token expr. If expr is defined here `http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=define` as of today, then the "+" operator is hinted at when it says `ISPP uses C/C++-like expression syntax. It supports simple and compound assignment operators, conditional operator, and sequential evaluation operator.` If there is a better definition for expr I haven't found it.